# ASP.Net MVC - Overriding a form between assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Here is the context of my job's application:

- Core assembly

  - ModelBase model
  - MyController.Save(ModelBase model)
- Site1 assembly

  - MyModel: ModelBase
- Site2 assembly

  - MyModel: ModelBase

Both Site1 and Site2 reference Core assembly and are deployed websites.

Core act as a library which references asp mvc assembly.

```cs
public class ModelBase : IValidatableObject
{
    public virtual String FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual String LastName { get; set; }
    //[...] IValidatableObject stuff
}
```

```cs
public class MyController:Controller{
    public ActionResult Save(ModelBase model){
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View(model);
        return Redirect("/Success");
    }
}
```

Now in Site1 assembly I have something like this

```
public class MyModel : ModelBase
{
    [Required]
    [Display(/*...*/)]
    public override String FirstName { get; set; }
    public override String LastName { get; set; }
}
```

And in Site2 assembly I have something like this

```
public class MyModel : ModelBase
{
    public override String FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(/*...*/)]
    public override String LastName { get; set; }
}
```

What I would like is:

- To have the saving logic (Save method of MyController) **only** in the Core assembly
- Be able in every Site*.MyModel to say this field is mandatory or not and thus having the controller to act regarding this.
- **If the model is not valid, I'd like to have the concrete model (MyModel) in the view instead of the "base" model (ModelBase) and so the view would display & generate the right validation stuff.**

Thank you for your help, ping me if you need more details :)